# Better way to check if a list of IDs is valid (EF Core)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a list of checkbox elements in a html page, all selectable and with distinct IDs, and its IDs are send by HTTP POST to my API. For security, I need to check if any of the sent IDs is invalid. It is just a method that returns false if any of those IDs does not exists in my database, and returns true if all of those exists.

It looked easy initially, but I didn't find a way to return that result from my database directly using EF Core. I always need to compare the `Count` of my query result with my list `Count`.

My better approach was:

```
public async Task<bool> IsIdListValid(IEnumerable<int> idList) =>
   (await _context.Foo
              .Select(x => x.Id)
              .CountAsync(id => idList.Contains(id))
   ) == idList.Distinct().Count();
```

So, what I'm asking is: there is a better way to write that query, more readable and performant?

Comment: What about `.All`?

Comment: `.All`, in my entity, is not able to search for an invalid id in my IEnumerable list. `.All` in my IEnumerable list is not a SQL valid query, just in memory. Camilo approach was the better until now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`All`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public async Task<bool> IsIdListValid(IEnumerable<int> idList)  
{
   var validIds = await _context.Foo.Select(x => x.Id).ToListAsync();
   return idList.All(x => validIds.Contains(x));
}
```

Comment: If idList is empty, won't this return true? Perhaps not what's intended.

Comment: Until now it was the better awnser. If no one found better solution, I will accept your question as valid. I already have a null/empty validation in my FluentValidation class

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 That's not what this method should be looking anyway

Comment: why do you think that select all ids is better than Count with a filter condition?

Answer (score 4):

assume you have list of ids with name 'idsLst', so you will get all matched ids from db and then compare the returned id list returned from db with your list if they are identical, so all list items are exist in db, if there's diff, it's mean you have some invalid Ids

```
var validIds = DbContext
    .UREntity
    .Where(x => idsLst.Contains(x.Id))
    .Select(x => x.Id);
    

var invalidIdsLst = ids.Except(validIds);

return invalidIdsLst.Count == 0; // return true if all valid
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some explanation too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of verifying by count, you can implement your question directly:

```
public async Task<bool> IsIdListValid(IEnumerable<int> idList) =>
    idList.Any(id => !_context.Foo.Any(f => f.id == id));
```

This will send on SQL query per member of `idList` when it is valid. If `idList` is short, this might be okay, otherwise your `Count` query is probably best, though the `Select` isn't needed. This will shortcut however if `idList` contains an invalid member, stopping on the first invalid member.

Another possiblity is using the [EntityFrameworkCore.MemoryJoin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkCore.MemoryJoin) extension that adds the ability to send an in-memory list using SQL `VALUES` and then join to it.

Comment: Unfortunatelly is possible the idList not be short. Thanks for you awnser, i will also read about the `MemoryJoin` too